# Display a default image when image path empty in sql

Tags: php, sql, image

I have checked the questions and there is not really one specific to what I am trying to achieve. I want to load a default image from my images folder if the image path is missing from my database. Can someone please tell me how to go about this. This is what I have so far:

```
    $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Comment, Image_path FROM comment";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows >0){
    // output data for each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $firstLetter =  substr($row["Name"], 0, 1); 
        echo '<div class="my-comment">';
        echo '<img src='.$row["Image_path"].'><br>'.'<p class="name">'.$firstLetter. $row["Name"]." wrote :".'<p class="comments">'.$row["Comment"]."</p>"."<br>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo "There are currently No Approved Comments.";
}
```

Comment: db image path is absolute path or relative path.

Comment: check if `Image_path` is empty, like so `echo '<img src=' . (empty($row["Image_path"]) ? '/path_to_default_image/filename.png' : $row["Image_path"]) . '>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code using ternary operator.

```
echo '<img src="'.( trim( $row["Image_path"] ) != "" ? $row["Image_path"] : "images/default.png" ).'"><br>'.'<p class="name">'.$firstLetter. $row["Name"]." wrote :".'<p class="comments">'.$row["Comment"]."</p>"."<br>";
```

If `$row["Image_path"]` is not empty, then the value of that is set. Otherwise it's set to a default image.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. I really appreciate it. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

please paste this line just after while, and then use the $Image_path variable to show it.

`$Image_path = $row["Image_path"] ? "path/to/default/image.jpg";`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will that check the database to see if an image path is empty before displaying the default image?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will that check the database to see if an image path is empty before displaying the default image?